# CSS Vertical Space Issue for JQuery Galleriffic Slideshow

Tags: jquery, css

The Main Photo of the SlideShow appears differently for it's Left Margin between IE7 and IE8 and Firefox.

Within IE there are several pixels extra vertical space for the SlideShow Image that do not show-up for the Controls Div (Blue Div w/ Play Slideshow).

However, the SlideShow Div and Controls Div appear correct for the Left-Margin in Firefox.

Here is how the Image appears with my IE8 Browser:

[image]

I cant determine why there is extra vertical space.

Here is the Development Site:  http://www.davincispainting.com/InteriorGallery.aspx

The name of the CSS is:  galleriffic-2.css.

Comment: The answer is to remove the `&nbsp;`s that @clairesuzy points out, and to add some `margin-bottom` to an element such as `div.controls`, for example `margin: 5px 0 18px 53px`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="slideshow" class="slideshow">
  <span style="opacity: 1;" class="image-wrapper current">
    <a class="advance-link" rel="history" href="#bigleaf" title="Title #2">
&nbsp;
      <img src="images/Portfolio/Interior/Normal/InteriorPic2a.jpg" alt="Title #2">
     </a>
  </span>
</div>
```

That `&nbsp;` is what's causing the vertical gap in IE, it's causing a horizontal gap in others :o it would be better to remove it and use a margin on the image if you want a horizontal gap

Comment: I found that this (&nbsp;) was being inserted w/in a hidden span that was being created within the javascript.  Do you know if this now functions in IE9?

Comment: @Paul glad it worked, for IE7/8 anyway -  I'm sorry I don't know about IE9 and can't test, but I would imagine not as I don't think that change would be enough

Answer (score 0):

You can just simply add IE's css hack on this, specific for IE6/7/8, ex:

```
margin: 5px 0 0 55px\9; // it's for IE8
*margin: 5px 0 0 55px; // it's for IE7
_margin: 5px 0 0 55px; // it's for IE6
```

but actually your most serious problem is that the slideshow doesn't even work on IE9, you should probably try to fix this or switch to other plugins.

Cheers

Comment: that is a serious problem.  Do you think that this is an inherent problem with the Plugin?

Comment: It would cost you lots of time to fix the plugin itself, however you can switch to other plugins which there are plenty over google search. This may help: http://www.1stwebdesigner.com/css/fresh-jquery-image-gallery-display-solutions/ Cheers